# How to set permission for exposed filter in Views block

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a View with several blocks or displays. In one of these displays I have added the filter "Published" and made it exposed, so that user can switch between published and unpublished content.

Now I only want users with the administrator role to be able to see this filter, but I cannot figure out how to do this. 
Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you expose the filter as a block from within the view (Advanced - exposed form in block) then you could set the permissions on the exposed form block in the block system to Admin role users. Alternatively I can only think that you might need to use hook_form_alter to amend the permissions on that form if you want everyone others to see the view but not the exposed form.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. The option 'Exposed form in block' requires the page display, and is not available for the block display. My view consists of 6 different blocks. There has to be a solution, but I still haven't found it.

Answer (score 1):

I post the answer myself in case anyone is having the same problem. The solution was to use views-view--display_name.tpl.php and simply add a check if the user is admin or not for the exposed item... like this:

```
<?php global $user; ?>
<?php if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)):?>
  <?php if ($exposed): ?>
    <div class="view-filters">
      <?php print $exposed; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```